# How do I pass prop to component in slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do i pass prop from app.vue to parentComponent slot, and make it still reactive?
Now, the code look like this below, but when i change data in app.vue, the prop in child does not change.

parentComponent.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref, useSlots, VNode, readonly  } from "vue"
const slots = useSlots()
const pageSlots = slots.default ? slots.default() : []
const currentStep = ref(0)
const currentPage = ref<VNode>(pageSlots[0])
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <transition mode="out-in">
        <keep-alive>
          <suspense>
            <component :is="currentPage"/>
          </suspense>
        </keep-alive>
      </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

childComponent.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const prop = defineProp({
  msg: string
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>{{ prop.msg }}</div>
</template>
```

app.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const data1 = ref("123")
const data2 = ref("456")
const data3 = ref("789")
</script>
<template>
  <parent>
   <child :msg="data"/>
   <child :msg="data"/>
   <child :msg="data"/>
  </parent>
</template>
```

i want to pass prop to child which it still reactive, but dont pass to parent and parent pass pass to child to make it reactive.

Comment: Hi, I think you can use `inject` and `provide` in this case.

Comment: if this component is for specified service, then i will use inject. But it ins't, so i'm try to make it not to hard to use.